# What is Amazon AWS CloudWatch alarm 1 datapoint (1577523.0) was less than the threshold

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-cloudwatch

Amazon AWS CloudWatch has the following Alarm in an alarmed state [image: AWS cloudwatch]

- What caused it to get into this state?
- Why is it still in this state, as my application is not currently being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudWatch alarms have three possible states:

- **ALARM:** This means the condition is TRUE. It is typically associated with a condition that should trigger an alert or an auto-scaling action.
- **OK:** This means the condition is FALSE. It typically means "don't worry, everything's fine".
- **INSUFFICIENT DATA:** This means there is not enough data for the state to be determined. Typically caused by an alarm configured for a period of time (eg Average over 5 minutes) where there is insufficient data (eg less than 5 minutes of data).

The **ALARM** condition can look scary when associated with a scale-down alarm because it doesn't mean anything is 'wrong'. Rather, it just means TRUE. Sometimes I wish they'd call it something other than 'ALARM' since people sometimes get worried when this state is perfectly OK.

Answer (score 1):

Your alarm triggers if the amount of outgoing network usage is less than the configured threshold. Given that you say that your application is not currently being used it sounds normal for it to be in this state.

When using alarms to trigger scale up/down behaviour, it's normal that the scale down alarm is active when usage is low. It won't actually do anything in general since it can't make the number of instances less than the minimum you've allowed.